# Optimizing Slow SQL Query

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, recursive-query

I have a query and it uses MySQL as its database. Now I'm going nuts as to why it took 11 minutes to render result, I have like 7K+ records on my table and running a recursive subquery(?), I'm not entirely sure if this is what eats up the memory but if you could look and give some remedy as to how can this be optimized I would be very happy and contented...

My goal is to compress records relative to a particular person... And rank them based on time finished.

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `temptbl_raceeventresult_step1` (
`RunCatEventId` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`RunEventId` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`CategoryId` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`FullName` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`BIB` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`Category` DECIMAL(16,3) NOT NULL,
`Ord` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`TransitionId` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`Time` DATETIME NOT NULL)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

//Query

```
SELECT
UCASE(g1.Name) Name
,g1.BIB
,g1.TimeDerived
,g1.CategoryName
,g1.TotalPace
,g1.Category
,COUNT(*) AS rank
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        a.FullName Name, 
        a.RunCatEventId, 
        a.RunEventId, 
        a.CategoryId, 
        a.BIB, 
        a.Category, 
        a.Ord, 
        a.TransitionId,
        SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(Time) - (SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(Time) TimeMinuend FROM temptbl_raceeventresult_step1 WHERE BIB = a.bib AND (Ord + 1) = a.Ord AND CategoryId = a.CategoryId))) TimeDerived,
        SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(Time) - (SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(Time) TimeMinuend FROM temptbl_raceeventresult_step1 WHERE BIB = a.bib AND (Ord + 1) = a.Ord AND CategoryId = a.CategoryId)) / a.Category) TotalPace                              
    FROM temptbl_raceeventresult_step1 a                                      
    JOIN (SELECT @cat:=null) xyz
    GROUP BY a.RunCatEventId, a.RunEventId, a.CategoryId, a.FullName, a.BIB
) g1
JOIN
(
    SELECT 
        a.FullName Name, 
        a.RunCatEventId, 
        a.RunEventId, 
        a.CategoryId, 
        a.BIB, 
        a.Category, 
        a.Ord, 
        a.TransitionId,
        SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(Time) - (SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(Time) TimeMinuend FROM temptbl_raceeventresult_step1 WHERE BIB = a.bib AND (Ord + 1) = a.Ord AND CategoryId = a.CategoryId))) TimeDerived,
        SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(Time) - (SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(Time) TimeMinuend FROM temptbl_raceeventresult_step1 WHERE BIB = a.bib AND (Ord + 1) = a.Ord AND CategoryId = a.CategoryId)) / a.Category) TotalPace                              
    FROM temptbl_raceeventresult_step1 a                                      
    JOIN (SELECT @cat:=null) xyz
    GROUP BY a.RunCatEventId, a.RunEventId, a.CategoryId, a.FullName, a.BIB
) g2
ON (g2.TimeDerived, g2.bib) <= (g1.TimeDerived, g1.bib) AND g1.Category = g2.Category

WHERE g2.Category = 5 AND g1.RunEventId = 3

GROUP BY g1.Name
,g1.BIB
,g1.TimeDerived
,g1.CategoryName
,g1.TotalPace
,g1.Category
ORDER BY g1.Category, rank
```

Comment: Please add the log of `EXPLAIN`-ing this query to the question.

Comment: How long does one of the subqueries take? How many rows does it return? Adding indexes for the columns in the `GROUP BY` could help that.

Comment: I tried running the query it returned 3K compressed records. The total execution time was roughly 11mins.